# GKE workload logs not appearing in stackdriver

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

We implemented logging on our NodeJS applications that are containerized, all the logs get captured when running in the local docker environment. They're currently hosted in GKE From last 30 days, we're not been able to see any workload logs generated from the NodeJS application.

Here's the cluster configuration
[image]
[image]

We're only able to see the audit logs generated from GKE

[image]

[Edit]
Output of `kubectl describe pod <workload>`

````
Name:         anchorservice-c4fbb48b7-fgb4p
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         gke-default-pool-e0e18ef3-cjkb/10.128.0.121
Start Time:   Thu, 26 Aug 2021 05:34:18 +0530
Labels:       app=anchorservice
              io.kompose.service=anchorservice
              pod-template-hash=c4fbb48b7
              tier=backend
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/limit-ranger: LimitRanger plugin set: cpu request for container anchorservice
Status:       Running
IP:           10.4.3.9
IPs:
  IP:           10.4.3.9
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/anchorservice-c4fbb48b7
Containers:
  anchorservice:
    Container ID:   docker://---removed----
    Image:          ---removed----
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://---removed---
    Port:           8081/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Thu, 26 Aug 2021 05:34:34 +0530
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Requests:
      cpu:      100m
    Liveness:   http-get http://:8081/api/healthz delay=3s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:  http-get http://:8081/api/healthz delay=3s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      NODE_ENV:                             production
      PORT:                                 8081
      MONGODB_URL:                          <set to the key 'url' in secret 'mongo-db'>  Optional: false
      REDIS_URL:                            redis://redis-master.default.svc.cluster.local
      VAULT_ENDPOINT:                       http://vault:8200
      VAULT_KEY:                            default (v1:metadata.namespace)
      VAULT_TOKEN:                          <set to the key 'token' in secret 'removed'>  Optional: false
      CONFIG_MONGODB_URL:                   <set to the key 'url' in secret 'removed'>  Optional: false
      ENC_MASTER_KEY:                       <set to the key 'value' in secret 'removed'>   Optional: false
      APP_NAME:                             ANCHORSERVICE
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOST:                   http://elasticsearch-master:9200
      ENCRYPTED_INIT_KEY:                   ---removed----
      
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-n7vd7 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  default-token-n7vd7:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-n7vd7
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                 From                                                       Message
  ----     ------     ----                ----                                                       -------
  Warning  Unhealthy  12m (x3 over 3h4m)  kubelet, gke-default-pool-e0e18ef3-cjkb  Liveness probe failed: Get http://10.4.3.9:8081/api/healthz: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)```
````

Comment: How are you writing logs ? Are you writing to stdout and stderr ?

Comment: I am using Winston for logging. It prints to stdout. When I perform `kubectl logs -f <workload-id>` it shows all the logs.

Comment: Please check your logging pod. Run `kubectl describe pod <your logging pod> and paste output to the question.

Comment: Please don't use pastebin. Please edit your question and attach this output directly to the question.

Comment: `Liveness probe failed`. It means your application is dead. Have you tried restarting it? Have you tried to get to it manually? Basically, either your app is actually dead or it's showing the endpoint incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

The first point is to check if the service account associated with the workload running on a particular node has been granted with the [Logs Writer](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/access-control#logging.logWriter) role. Also, check if there is any logs exclusion filter configured in the logs router section.

Secondly, certain logs on a node may not be exported to Cloud Logging due to high logging throughput on the node. The GKE logging agent officially supports a logging throughput of [100 KB/s per node.](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/view-logs#:%7E:text=Logging%20supports%20up%20to%20100KB/s%20per%20node%20of%20logging%20throughput) When the logging throughput per node exceeds this threshold (e.g., greater than ~200 KB/s), the logging agent may not have sufficient resources to process all logs, leading to some logs not being exported to Cloud Logging.

you may also [enable high-throughput logging](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/adjust-log-throughput#enable).